# Header and its data not arranging properly

Tags: pageblocktable, repeat

```
<table width="100%">
              <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
                  <th>Clinical Study</th>
                 <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Versioname</th>
               </tr>
              </table>  
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!visitTemplates}" var="templist" rules="rows"> 
                 <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Site_Visit_Plan__c.FieldSets.Visit_Plan_Template}" var="f"> 
                    <apex:column> 
                        <apex:outputField value="{!templist[f.fieldPath]}"> </apex:outputField>
                     </apex:column>  
                    </apex:repeat>

           </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you creating two separate columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating two separate table create PageblockTable

Use `headervalue="{!f.label}"` to get the Field Label name. and remove your first table.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!visitTemplates}" var="templist" rules="rows"> 
     <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Site_Visit_Plan__c.FieldSets.Visit_Plan_Template}" var="f"> 
        <apex:column headervalue="{!f.label}"> 
            <apex:outputField value="{!templist[f.fieldPath]}"> </apex:outputField>
         </apex:column>  
        </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```